# Why is the UI Automation instrument unable to determine if a button is enabled here?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, instruments, ios-ui-automation

I am working with Xcode 4.0.1 and Instruments trying to implement some UIAutomation tests.

As of right now, I am trying to determine if a button on my MainWindow (`mainWindow = app.mainWindow();`) is enabled.

This is an app running on an iPad II, and right now I am not feeling the love.

Can anyone assist?

Here is the syntax I am trying to use; does this seem correct?

```
var title="Checking that Sign-In button is disabled";  
try {  
    if (mainWindow.buttons()["Sign In"].isEnabled())  
    UIALogger.logPass("Try: " + title + " has passed.");  
}  
catch (error) {  
    UIALogger.logError(error);  
    target.logElementTree();  
    UIALogger.logFail("Try: " + title + " has failed.");  
}
```

Comment: You should determine, what exactly is your problem! Is the button accessable at all? Is the path to the button correct (try to .tap() it or do an .logElementTree() on the mainWindow). This question cannot be answered if we do not know how your interface is organized... Your syntax seems correct, so it must be a problem with teh accessability of the button. Moreover try to interprete Instrument's error messages on script execution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey.
I agree with Sosullivan. There may be problem with button access in general. Additionally, if mainWindow.buttons() doesn't contain one with name "Sign In" isn't whole code executed without any output? I would get sure, that button is in object tree, verify its position (so I can access it) then call .isEnabled() to see if it is enabled for user.
maybe try this code for start:

```
var title="Checking that Sign-In button is disabled";  
try {
  if (mainWindow.buttons()["Sign In"] && mainWindow.buttons()["Sign In"].isEnabled())  {
      UIALogger.logPass("Try: " + title + " has passed.");  
  } else {
      throw new Error("no SignIn button or button not enabled");
    }
} catch (error) {  
  UIALogger.logError(error);  
  target.logElementTree();  
  UIALogger.logFail("Try: " + title + " has failed.");  
}
```

First check in `if` will check if button was found in tree structure (under main app). If it doesn't solve the issue check where in your tree structure the button is located, then put proper location verification as precondition to checking if it is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

In your code if button is disabled the following expression will be False

```
mainWindow.buttons()["Sign In"].isEnabled()
```

and your code do not have else statement for that and error won't be throwed as well.

You should have else structure or even better- check first if object you are accessing exists at all in your current window as shown in answer by [yoosiba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52564/yoosiba).

Answer (score 0):

You should use method .isVisible in this case as you want to check if a object exists or not.

```
if (mainWindow.buttons()["Sign In"].isVisible())  
    UIALogger.logPass("Try: " + title + " has passed.");
```

Answer (score -1):

Hrm. Ok....

We work using a UIAutomation opensource framework called, "alexvollmer-tuneup_js" taken off of SourceForge. It is freely available, and modifications are encouraged (and the author requests that you branch your versions of his code to share with others).

He has a file named assertions.js to which he has two functions assertTrue(), and assertFalse().

I use those in another file that he includes called 'uiautomation-ext.js' that is imported into my test file(s). In uiautomation-ext.js, I have added two functions:

```
/**
* Asserts that the given button is disabled.
*/
buttonIsDisabled: function(buttonName) {
        assertFalse(UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()[buttonName].isEnabled(), "The button: " + buttonName + " is disabled.");
},

/**
* Asserts that the given button is ENABLED.
*/
buttonIsEnabled: function(buttonName) {
        assertTrue(UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()[buttonName].isEnabled(), "The button: " + buttonName + " is enabled.");
}
```

These two functions are placed within a JDOS object within uiautomation-ext.js called 'extend(UIAWindow.prototype'.

I am not entirely sure that I have conveyed what I/we have done as clearly as I would like, but I have done my best here. Good luck to all!

SteveO